# Do activity and service functions sometimes run in parallel?

Tags: android, android-activity

Android - Does it sometimes happen that the functions in an activity and a service (like onCreate...) are called from different threads in parallel?

I have an Android app with an activity and a service that interact with each other and sometimes access the same data. So, do I have to be afraid of race conditions or other threading problems?

**Update:** Here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services it says:

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise.

which sounds like the answer is no, I do not have to be afraid. Is this true, or did I miss something?

Comment: short answer, you have to consider race conditions being caused, yes.

Comment: consider the fact that , something as simple as a button being pressed, could cause a race condition for you depending on the state of your service, so it really is something you have to consider

Comment: Actually, I found a hint that it is probably not a problem, see my updated question.